# Copying text changing some variables

Tags: python, file, text

I want to copy a text like this one (it is stored in a txt file, say *template.txt*) :

```
//
// Pyrolysis of PMMA sample exposed to a 18 kW/m² cone irradiances
//
MODULE PEL_Application
   $DS_external_flux= 16.5e03 // 18 kW/m² en prenant en compte le transfert convectif.
   $DS_DX = 0.005
   $DS_activation_energy = 1.15e+5
   $DS_arrhenius_constant = 7.0e+6
   $DS_Kappa_s = 1000.
   $DS_initial_fuel_mass = 1.50272
   $DS_heat_of_pyrolysis = 2.0e+6
   $DS_T_initial = 304.75
   $DS_gas_refractive_index = 1.0
   $DS_medium_refractive_index = 1.0
END MODULE PEL_Application

#include ( join( "..", "ref.pel" ) )
MODULE PEL_Application
   MODULE PDE_DomainAndFields
      MODULE macro_boundary_conditions
         MODULE BC#inlet1
            MODULE BC#temperature
               type  = "volumetric_pyrolysis#semi_transparent_media"
            END MODULE BC#temperature
         END MODULE BC#inlet1
      END MODULE macro_boundary_conditions
   END MODULE PDE_DomainAndFields
END MODULE PEL_Application
```

And I want to replace the values of

```
   $DS_activation_energy = 1.15e+5
   $DS_arrhenius_constant = 7.0e+6
```

with

```
   $DS_activation_energy = new_value_1
   $DS_arrhenius_constant = new_value_2
```

and copy the whole text in a new file called *data.txt* with the new values.

How can this be done in Python please ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything? You might want to check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Start with a loop (use `while open('file') as fd:...` Check each line, if a match, do the replace. Or use regexp. Please post some code and we'll gladly help!

Comment: in template.txt you could use 'placeholders' instead of actual values for variables you want to set later (e.g. "<activation_energy>" and "<arrhenius_constant>"

Comment: @Don : thank you, do you know a link to some documentation on these "placeholders" ? I am new to Python !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
f = open("template.txt", "r")
g = open("data.txt", "w")
lines = f.readlines()
new_value_1 = "Whatever"
new_value_2 = "Whatever else"
for each in lines:
    if each.strip().startswith("$DS_activation_energy"):
        split_val = each.split("=")
        split_val[-1] = new_value_1
        new_val = "= ".join(split_val) + "\n"
        g.write(new_val)
    elif each.strip().startswith("$DS_arrhenius_constant"):
        split_val = each.split("=")
        split_val[-1] = new_value_2
        new_val = "= ".join(split_val) + "\n"
        g.write(new_val)
    else:
        g.write(each)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.

```
import fileinput
import sys

for line in fileinput.input('File.txt', inplace=1):
        if 'string_to_replace' in line:
                line = line.replace('string_to_replace','new_string')
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do comme ça:

```
import re

rgx = re.compile('(\A.+?\$DS_activation_energy[ \t]*=[ \t]*)'
                 '[^ \t\r\n]+'
                 '(.+?\$DS_arrhenius_constant[ \t]*=[ \t]*)'
                 '[^ \t\r\n]+'
                 '(.+\Z)',
                 re.DOTALL)

with open('template.txt','rb') as f:
    cont = f.read()

new_value_1,new_value_2 = 10, 892.12

with open('data.txt','wb') as f:
    f.write(rgx.sub('\\1%s\\2%s\\3',cont) % (new_value_1,new_value_2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which makes use of 'placeholders'.

template.txt

```
//
// Pyrolysis of PMMA sample exposed to a 18 kW/m² cone irradiances
//
MODULE PEL_Application
   $DS_external_flux= 16.5e03 // 18 kW/m² en prenant en compte le transfert convectif.
   $DS_DX = 0.005
   $DS_activation_energy = <activation_energy>
   $DS_arrhenius_constant = <arrhenius_constant>
   $DS_Kappa_s = 1000.
   $DS_initial_fuel_mass = 1.50272
   $DS_heat_of_pyrolysis = 2.0e+6
   $DS_T_initial = 304.75
   $DS_gas_refractive_index = 1.0
   $DS_medium_refractive_index = 1.0
END MODULE PEL_Application

#include ( join( "..", "ref.pel" ) )
MODULE PEL_Application
   MODULE PDE_DomainAndFields
      MODULE macro_boundary_conditions
         MODULE BC#inlet1
            MODULE BC#temperature
               type  = "volumetric_pyrolysis#semi_transparent_media"
            END MODULE BC#temperature
         END MODULE BC#inlet1
      END MODULE macro_boundary_conditions
   END MODULE PDE_DomainAndFields
END MODULE PEL_Application
```

Now, read 'template.txt' and replace values:

```
with open('template.txt') as input_file:
    template_text = input_file.read()

new_activation_energy = ...
new_arrhenius_constant = ...

new_text = template_text
new_text = new_text.replace('<activation_energy>', new_activation_energy)
new_text = new_text.replace('<new_arrhenius_constant >', new_arrhenius_constant)

with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as ouput_file:
    output_file.write(new_text)
```